# How to return a field from a static structure

Tags: rust

I have code:

```
static mut SETTINGS: Option<Settings> = None;

pub struct Settings {
    pub(crate) db_path: String,
    pub(crate) is_debug: bool
}

pub fn create_settings(settings: Settings) {
    unsafe {
        SETTINGS = Option::from(settings)
    }
}

pub mod get {
    pub fn db_path() -> String {
        unsafe {super::SETTINGS.expect("Settings not definition").db_path}
    }
}
```

And I get errors

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of static item `SETTINGS`
  --> src/settings.rs:16:17
   |
16 |         unsafe {super::SETTINGS.expect("Settings not definition").db_path}
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `SETTINGS` has type `std::option::Option<Settings>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I need a static structure and get fields from it. How do I write getter functions so I can just call functions and get settings instead of passing a reference to a struct. Settings are global and alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`once_cell::OnceCell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/sync/struct.OnceCell.html#method.set) for that (notice that it can be set just once):

```rust
use once_cell::sync::OnceCell;


static SETTINGS: OnceCell<Settings> = OnceCell::new();

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Settings {
    pub(crate) db_path: String,
    pub(crate) is_debug: bool
}

pub fn create_settings(settings: Settings) {
    SETTINGS.set(settings).expect("Set should occur only once")
}

pub mod get {
    pub fn db_path<'a>() -> &'a str {
        &super::SETTINGS.get().expect("Settings not definition").db_path
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=957b0ed9b91542b154303f5d6b4fe811)

Also notice that the return type of `db_path` changed, it is now `&'a str`, you can return a reference to the string. If you really want it to return a `String` then you would have to `Clone` it.

Most probably you would need also just plain `OnceCell`, your methods would be just wrapper around it (access and setting).

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the Option that you only want a reference to its contents, rather than taking them. Then you need to clone the value.

```
pub mod get {
    pub fn db_path() -> String {
        unsafe {
            super::SETTINGS
                .as_ref()
                .expect("Settings not definition")
                .db_path
                .clone()
        }
    }
}
```